# Restrict .ics file from forwarding

Tags: c#, icalendar

I'm able to create and send .ics files using the below code.

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("test@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com");

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting");
        str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
        str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(+330)));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(+660)));
        str.AppendLine("LOCATION: " + "abcd");
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", msg.Subject));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));

        str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));

        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
        str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
        str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
        str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
        str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
        str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.ToString());
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        Attachment attach = new Attachment(stream, "test.ics");

        msg.Attachments.Add(attach);

        System.Net.Mime.ContentType contype = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
        contype.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
        AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), contype);
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);

        using (SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
        {
            smtpclient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test@gmail.com", "*********");
            smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpclient.Send(msg);
        }
```

Is there a way that can restrict receivers to forward the invite to others? or can restrict the invite for the email of attendees specified?

Comment: So you want to limit the people that can add the event to their calendar by email?

Comment: Yes, I want to limit the event to the specified attendees. If any other got the event file they will not be able to add this to their calendar.

Comment: Depends largely on the email client, and anyone with even basic knowledge of email protocols will be able to bypass it on most clients, so if it’s critical that they can’t, the answer is almost certainly no.